# Show post only if match all categories

Tags: categories, get-posts, array

I have posts that have multiple different categories including a common category called "Videos", now I'm trying to show only posts that match with the all categories of the main post including the common "Video" category.

Suppose, the main post has: **Catagory A, Catagory B, Videos**

The output posts must be matching categories like this:

**Catagory A, Catagory B, Videos** (Output 1)

**Catagory A, Catagory B, Videos** (Output 2)

**Catagory A, Catagory B, Videos** (Output 3)...

With the following code, it's showing all the posts from "Videos" category:

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    $args=array(
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 30,
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('post-format-video'),
        'operator' => 'IN'
       ) )
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {?>
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { $my_query->the_post();?>
```

Comment: Can you indent your code? It's difficult to read ( also `wp_query` needs to be `WP_Query` )

Comment: Indented, hope it's easy to read now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version of your code that will get posts that have the *Post Format* `Video` *and* that have the same *Categories* as the current post in the loop.

You'll call `wpse_get_video_posts_with_matching_categories()` to execute the function.

```
function wpse_get_video_posts_with_matching_categories() {
    $categories = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );

    if ( empty ( $categories ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $my_query = new WP_Query( [
        'post__not_in'   => [ get_the_ID() ],
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'tax_query'      => [
            'relation' => 'AND', // We will check BOTH of the following criteria.
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => [ 'post-format-video' ],
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ],
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'term_id' ), // A handy way to extract data.
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ],
        ],
    ] );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <?php while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
                $my_query->the_post();
                // Output content...
                the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
}
```

I tested this and I think it's what you're after. Note that your original code is missing the part where we query against the term IDs. I also spruced things up a bit with some best practices.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for the input. I tried to implement it, but there's no output at all.

Comment: Here's my full section modified code according to your input:
https://gist.github.com/Tanvir741/097d2a471327840770eda0e74e4ab618


Original section code:
https://gist.github.com/Tanvir741/e012c91cbf8d4085ef0ca9be362c3c5b

Comment: Hi @Tanvir, place the function declaration that I posted in your theme's `functions.php` file, then call the function in the theme.